# Websecurity logout link using Webmatrix and Razor

Tags: razor, security, webmatrix

I am creating an application largely based on the template provided with WebMatrix 2.

Everything is working great, although I'm having some issues creating a "logout" link in my header.

Currently I have the following link:

```
<a href="~/account/logout.cshtml">Sign Out</a>
```

Which in turn, directs to this page:

```
@{
    WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    if (IsPost) {
        // Verify the request was submitted by the user
        AntiForgery.Validate();

        // Log out of the current user context
        WebSecurity.Logout();

        // Redirect back to the return URL or homepage
        var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
    } else {
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

But when I click this link, it does nothing, and I'm still logged in. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default logout links are (and should be) validated POST requests, this is to prevent XSS attacks of logging your users out by redirecting them to the logout page.

Thanks to this code:

```
if (IsPost) {
    // Verify the request was submitted by the user
    AntiForgery.Validate();
```

.. you will need to create a form for logging out, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="~/account/logout.cshtml">
    @AntiForgery.GetHtml()
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

Of course, you can use JavaScript to have a normal link submit that form, thus making it look like a normal link to the end user, only they're protected!

Comment: Do you have a link to some JavaScript that would achieve that? i just tried the form menthod, which works, but it throws all the formatting out the window?

Comment: Stick an `id` on your form, hide it out of view and do `document.getElementById('formid').submit();`.